# Displaying XML file data from a MySQL query using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, xml

I am attempting to use a MySQL Query:

```
mysql -h hostName -u username -p databaseName --xml -e 'select * from example' > testData.xml
```

That will output a file which looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultset statement="select * from equipment
" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
                <field name="id">5</field>
                <field name="name">arduino</field>
                <field name="quantity">50</field>
  </row>

  <row>
        <field name="id">7</field>
        <field name="name">raspberry pi</field>
        <field name="quantity">50</field>
  </row>
</resultset>
```

I am then attempting to use an XMLHttpRequest to get the text value of one of these fields.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "testData.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
    
function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("row")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

However, nothing is displayed in the "demo" (element is a paragraph) and no errors are shown in the Chrome console. My Javascript isn't the best, but I have tested the code using W3Schools examples and the code works fine. Doing a childElementCount will return a correct '3' so it knows that the fields are there. So my assumption is that the formatting of the XML is incorrect, more precisely the "field name = "id"" section as this appears differently in other examples of XML files.

Is there a way to return XML from a MySQL query that will function correctly with the code? Or is there a way to get this code to run correctly.

Comment: Is the AJAX call returning the XML content? (check with your browser's developer tools)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Under the Network tab in Chrome I can see it is fetching the file ok. I can see all the data in there (if that's what you meant).

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking.